# changing self.view frame doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following structure:

UIViewController > UIView (self.view) > UITableView (self.tableView - IBOutlet)

I'm trying to move the whole thing up by 59 pixels, I tried:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -59, 320, 367 + 59);
    // or
    self.tableViewMe.frame = CGRectMake(0, -59, 320, 367 + 59);;

    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.height);

    NSLog(@"%f", self.tableView.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.tableView.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.tableView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.tableView.frame.size.height);

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

The coordinates are right but the view and the table are the same, not moving at all. Besides, If I add the following code to a IBAction, like a button tap, then it works:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -59, 320, 367 + 59);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sticking it in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear.

Comment: The IBOutlets only get wired correctly after the view loads fully. I generally place it in the viewDidLoad method ;)

Comment: viewDidLoad runs once. I need to check it everytime the user enters the view controller. =/

Comment: viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad.  viewDidAppear runs everytime the viewController appears.

Comment: Yeah, was just confirming that. You said viewDidLoad only runs once... this is correct, but irrelevant in this case as you are not putting the code in viewDidLoad, you are putting it in viewDidAppear :D

Comment: I was responding to iLive. Also, now my view is being reseted to the original position in the will disappear even if the method is empty.

Comment: Please, take a look, maybe you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235879/view-frame-being-reseted-in-will-disappear-even-if-the-method-is-empty